# How could I setup a AWS Config rule for any changes made to my Instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-auto-scaling, aws-config

I have EC2 Instances launching automatically from my AMI setup to a LB and ASG. I want to now configure a security service like AWS Config to monitor my EC2 Instance for any Configuration changes.

The issue I am having is knowing which rule in AWS Managed Rule monitors the configuration as I don't see any that specifically does. I see `alb-http-to-https-redirection-check`, `cloudwatch-alarm-resource-check`, `desired-instance-tenancy`, `approved-amis-by-tag` and `ami-by-id`.

Not sure what to do to as none of these suit my use case.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the information How you can create config rule

you can select specific AWS Resource like EC2 instance from the resource list and then on second step you will find list of managed rules you can select all rules for configuration changes that you want to record for your instance.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't have them rules when I search for ec2, I only get back 5 results from inputting 'ec2' and none are the ones you selected. Could I set up a Config on my Load Balancer  instead to monitor the config?

Comment: I am not sure why you can not find in your AWS account. List of managed rules  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/config/latest/developerguide/managed-rules-by-aws-config.html

Comment: you can setup config on load balancer as well

Comment: I have setup one in Config for my Load Balancer to if any Config is changed it will notify me but under 'Integrated Services' under the Load Balancer it tells me that Config has not been setup for the Load Balancer even though I created a Rule specifically for it?

Comment: and I also have the Resource types within the Rule directed to the Elastic Load Balancer so I don't understand why it's not being picked up

Answer (score 0):

initially create config, without selecting any rules. Then later come back to the config, and click rules tab , and add rules. You should be able to see all the rules and select ones needed.